# SSH connection to jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, github, shell-script, bash

I have a absh script which connects and exexutes programs from my local to remote server and now this should be executed from jenkins build so for this jenkins is taking continous changes from git for this script but my build is failing with below error:

Warning: Identity file /c/Users/D35N/Downloads/GitHubProjeckt/Automation/GitHubProjeckt/newharbortestkey not accessible: No such file or directory.
Host key verification failed.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

I have tried to set ssh connectivity in my jenkins server for this remote server incredentials and ssh plugins but using my key i am getting an error cant connect to the server.

when i run the script from local it works fine and my ssh connection gets established properly using SSH key.

jenkins server is also integrated or installed on my kuberenets cluster which is my remote server in this case and bash script should execute on this kuberenets cluster.

Can anyone please suggest how this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration refers to a file that is local on your system, but does not exist on the jenkins server.  The error message is trying to tell you this.  `/c/Users/D35N/Downloads/GitHubProjeckt/Automation/GitHubProjeckt/newharbortestkey` is not on the jenkins server.  You need to make this file available on the jenkins server by copying it up there, and it probably shouldn't be in your personal `Downloads` folder.

You may want to configure your script to look for a series of files and use the first one that exists.  This will let you have the file at different locations on your development box versus the server and it will still work in either.

Comment: thanks could you please refer to my further error in answer section,sorry , it wasnt possible due to characters limit to post it in comment section

Comment: Howdy Sakshi, asking a new question in an answer is not the way to do things on StackExchange.  You've put in a lot of info.  You just need to make it a new question.